# numpy print matrix one row one line

Tags: python, numpy, printing

Print a numpy matrix,I want get one row in one line,but when the cols is large ,it print two or three lines .

```
a= np.random.rand(1,7)
print(a)

[[0.58402214 0.45091714 0.53607019 0.56363398 0.50127479 0.72100874

0.80735565]]---this is two lines

I expect [[0.58402214 0.45091714 0.53607019 0.56363398 0.50127479 0.72100874  0.80735565]]
```

Comment: select code and use button `{}` to format code.

Comment: when you edit text you have buttons/icons to set bold, italic, append image,etc. There is icon with `{}` to format code.

Comment: using Google "numpy format array" I found [numpy.set_printoptions](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.set_printoptions.html)

Answer (score 4):

you can [configure numpy print options](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/generated/numpy.set_printoptions.html).
if you never want line-wrapping for example, you can set linewidth:

```
import numpy as np

np.set_printoptions(linewidth=np.inf)

a = np.random.rand(1,13)
print(a)  # expected output
```